# Universal iOS 9.1 app is not compatible

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

I have a Universal App for iPad and iPhone.

the old versions of my app are working fine. I build the project with Xcode 7 and iOS 9.1 and it worked fine on my iPhone 6S and my iPad 2.

but after i upload the app to the AppStore i tried to update with my ipad and i get this message:

> That my App "is not compatible with this iPad"

here screenshot of the appstore:
[image]

**What i doing wrong?**

**UPDATE 1:**

My iPad version is iOS 9.1 and the target in XCode is Universal

Comment: Whats the iOS version of your iPad?

Comment: What did you set the target device as in Xcode?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog iOS 9.1

Comment: @Richard Griffiths the target is Universal

Comment: Perhaps it is a BETA iOs on your iPad?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff No it's not beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason the value of `Build Active Architecture Only` was `YES` instead of `NO`!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since the compatibility list doesn't show iPhone4S or iPhone5, I assume that you limited the architecture to `arm64`.

For further information, see [Setting Architectures for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW37).

Comment: No, i used "Standard Architectures"  (armv7,arm64).

Comment: Does "Valid Architectures" include `arm64`, `armv7` and `armv7s`?

Comment: Yes it's include all of them.